# Don't know where to put this package

Tags: android

I've been moving com.android.vending.billing literally everywhere but nothing seems to work. Where am I supposed to put this?

[image]

EDIT: PROBLEM #2
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? You shouldn't need to have source code for anything in that package in _your_ code, as `IInAppBillingService` is part of the Android library. Have you read http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html ?

Comment: You have to know what you're doing now. Every folder has its own function.

Comment: put that package in to java

Comment: @Nisarg i tried putting it into java, didnt work

Comment: @MattBall I have edited my question with the text straight from the docs

Comment: @Sheila Grant have you found solution yet?

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Comment: click on file menu and click on project structure and open it, now click on app in module and select Flavors tab and change application id to put your package name and click on ok button, try it and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij is telling you that it can't find vending in the package `com.android`.  I would guess your path is messed up or you need to add a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create directory folder in main directory name aidl and put your package in this directory.

main -> aidl -> com.android.vending.billing

Comment: thanks that worked but now theres a second problem. i have edited my question above

Comment: the above i don't find any changes where yo done it.

Comment: I dont know exitly but i have got this type error any library conflict from other libarary in project.

Answer (score 0):

Create folders corresponding to the package name inside /main/Java/ like /com/android/vending/billing/ and move IInAppBillingService.aidl inside that.

Or create the package using android studio and then move the aidl file. This will automatically create the folder structure.

[image]

Comment: thanks. i got the package stuff fixed. but now I have a new strange problem as seen in my edited question

Comment: im not sure why it is saying method cannot be found

Comment: When I remove that AIDL folder, I am back to where I started as you can see in my updated question

Comment: that is because your imports might still have the aidl at the start. I have it in my projects this way and is working perfectly fine. just check the import statements in the file where you see the error and remove the aidl from package names in import statements too.

Comment: But look at my updated question. None of its imports has "aidl" in them

Comment: can you do a clean and build again?

Comment: invalidate cache and restart? (from file menu)